# How to use different python versions for different python scripts within the same project in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, versions

I have a necessary module that is not compatible with python3, but the rest of my project runs in python3. Is there a way I could run only this module with python2 and the rest of my project with python3? How to do it in pycharm?

Comment: You can create 2 different virtual environment for 2 different project.

Comment: The short answer is: no. Have you considered forking the *"necessary module"* and upgrading it to Python 3, or altering your own code to be compatible with 2.x?

Comment: I'm using two libraries, which are not my code. One is not compatible with python3. The other is not compatible with python2.